# Where/When can I add something to the `UIWindow` in my `UIViewController`?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, containers, uiwindow

I am trying to add a view to my `UIWindow` so that it stays up there even if my `UIViewController` goes away.  I right now I am adding a `UIView` in my init method and I also tried my `viewDidLoad` method, but in both of them my `self.view.window` is nil.

If I use my same code in a tap method, the `UIWindow` is inited and the `UIView` gets added.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to do something that iOS does not want you to do (or does not want you to do in that specific way). Could you describe the problem that you are solving? Screen images may come in handy, too, if you are trying to achieve a particular visual effect.

Comment: I am trying to add a little view at the bottom about 70 pt high, like the Pinterest app has, when you pin something.  I can just add it to the viewcontroller, but I believe in the Pinterest app the view does not stay with the vie controller, it stays up even if the viewcontroller has gone away.  I am just messing around with it really.  Not too important to my project.

Comment: I am also looking into adding iAds throughout the whole app, instead of having an iAd appear for a split second, as in my app I anticipate that users won't be on one ViewController for more than a few seconds.

Answer (score 2):

A view controller's view isn't added to the window until the 1st time `viewWillAppear:` is called. This is why you see `nil` in `viewDidLoad` and certainly `init`.

If a view controller really needs to add something to the window, use:

```
UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
```